# Jquery, Ajax, BeforeSend and Show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've already searched on other questions but I can't find a good solution. I use jQuery 1.11 to do an Ajax request. I want to show "caricamento7" (it's a <span> with an image and text) during the request and I punt .show() on BeforeSend but it doesn't work.

If I put `alert("bye")` it works!

Thank you for your help

```
$.ajax({
url : "calcolo.php",
type: "GET",
data : {
           dato1: $("#leva").val()
       }
cache: false,
crossDomain: false,
dataType : "json",
timeout: 3000,
beforeSend: function () {
    $("#caricamento7").show();
},
success: function(data) {...
```

Comment: Explain "doesn't work". In which way doesn't it work?

Comment: Syntax errors in your JS would show up in the error console.  You should be looking their first whenever you have a problem.

Comment: Doesn't work -> the page freeze during ajax request and AFTER it the image appears. Thank you!

Comment: Any other suggestion? Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

```
dato1: $("#leva").val() //semicolon deleted
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I know. It's a copy-mistake... The problem is the $("#caricamento7").show(); inside beforeSend. If I write alert("hello!") it works but not hide-show function. Thank you